# How do I get javascript to send form to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have searched the questions and none directly addresses the issue I'm having. Please forgive me if it has been addressed; I could not find it.
I am making a form using JavaScript and trying to submit it, but when I do form.submit nothing happens. The page reloads, but it never gets to the PHP page to which I am directing it.

the JavaScript:

```
    function voteForName(name){
       var form2 = document.createElement("form");
       form2.setAttribute("method", "get");
       form2.setAttribute("action", "../php/namesSuggest.php");

       var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "babyName");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("value", name);
       form2.appendChild(hiddenField);

       document.body.appendChild(form2);
       alert(form2.outerHTML);
       form2.submit();  
     }
```

the html

```
            '<tr>
                <td width="33%"></td> 
                <td width="33%" align="center"><a href><p onclick="voteForName(\''. $obj["name"] .'\')" title="Click to vote for this name!" id="123'. $obj["name"] .'" >'
                    . $obj["name"] . 
                '</p></a></td>
                <td width="33%"></td>
              </tr>';
```

the html is being formed using php.
the folders are set up

```
site
    home
        fileWhereJSIsCalled.php
    php
        namesSuggestions.php
    js
        myJSfile.js
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: i am not getting any errors in the console. I just figured it out... the 'href' in the <a> tag was not letting it do what it needed to do

Comment: such as silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
form2.setAttribute("action", "php/namesSuggest.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `href` to the `<a>` tag would refresh the page and not let the javascript do it's thing.

Very silly mistake, but I am going to add the answer here just in case anyone else has this problem